# libblas.so, may conflict with libgfortran.so.5

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, fortran

I use Ubuntu inside Windows 10. I have a gfortran 4.8.5 and installed gfortran 9 by `sudo apt-get install gfortran-9` followed https://fortran-lang.org/learn/os_setup/install_gfortran

When I type `gfortran -v`, it still leads to 4.8.5. Nevertheless, `gfotran-9 -v` leads to `gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04)`

The problem is, when I use gfortran-9 compile a code, it leads to
 `/usr/bin/ld: warning: libgfortran.so.3, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib/libblas.so, may conflict with libgfortran.so.5`
The code can still run, but I would like to avoid any possible conflict.

I searched a few times, still unsure what kind of configuration I need to circumvent the above message. Thank you very much.